# Unable to call method which performing mouse actions to TestNG test case using selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

```
Main Block:
```

```
    public class test3 extends utility {
        public WebDriver driver;
        @BeforeTest
        public void invokeBrowser() throws IOException {
            driver = base();
            driver.get(resource.getProperty("url"));
    
        }
    
        @Test
        public class thirdPage {
            public void main() {
    
                actionTest test3 = new actionTest();
                test3.executeTest();
            }
        }
    
    }
```

**Code performing mouse Actions:**

```
public class actionTest {   
    
    public void executeTest() {
    Actions execute = new Actions();    
    execute.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("header-search-input"))).click().keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("Cricket").build().perform();
    driver.findElement(By.id("header-desktop-search-button")).click();
    }
    
    

}
```

> Above code results in "NullPointerException" stating driver = null while executing block test3.executeTest();

Comment: What returns `base()` method? Add it's code as well pls. Besides that check if there is not another declaration of `WebDriver driver`, in the `utility` class maybe.

Comment: Btw classes should be named with first letter in capital, Test3, Utility, ActionTest, etc.

Comment: @pgurbr : base() method is under utility class will initialize the WebDriver `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` . Clarification point is whether executeTest() method having mouse action activities will be called to @Test case thirdPage class. (Or) is there any other way to call executeTest() to @Test case class. Thanks !

Comment: The `base()` method has to return a `Webdriver` object (as WebDriver type) or set value for declared `WebDriver` object (as void).

Comment: @pburgr : Thank you, I got the issue from your suggestion! (Sorry for mentioning wrong name in my previous reply)

Answer (score 2):

Restructuring your codebase might help you to fix this issue. Create a base test class. Add the code related to web driver initialization and other main things there. Then create another class for your tests. Inherit it from the base test class. Then you can use the initialized driver in your all test classes.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I found the fix and it is working !

Comment: Great! @SukumarSiva